# SQL - Select and count without groupby

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't understand the output from this SQL command.

```
SELECT fk1, count(fk1) FROM Table1;
```

The input data is

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (pk1 int, fk1 int);

INSERT INTO Table1
    (pk1, fk1)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2),
    (5, 1),
    (6, 2),
    (7, 1),
    (8, 2);
```

the output is

```
fk1        count(fk1)
1          8
```

What is this SQL command actually doing internally?

This was tried from sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/698e31/1

Comment: This looks like MySql. With [mysql_only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)
enabled as it should be this would error - as it should do.

Comment: 'If you use an aggregate function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows. For more information, see Section 12.20.3, “MySQL Handling of GROUP BY ' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Becasue older version of mysql `sql_mode` is not eqaul `only_full_group_by` as default.

If your mysql version is higher than 5.7 that will set

```
sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

`sql_mode` as default setting (I would suggest it be opened).

> The default SQL mode in MySQL 5.7 includes these modes: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Enable `sql_mode` as `only_full_group_by` we might follow

> Reject queries for which the select list, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the `GROUP BY` clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined by) `GROUP BY` columns.

So that when we use aggregate function, we might need to let non-aggregate columns in group by (if we want to select them).

If you want to disable `sql_mode`, we can try to set `sql_mode = ''`

```
SET sql_mode = ''
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=80a4336ba57b327374ab582c495f9596)

Comment: I'm quite new to SQL - could you add a bit of further explanation here? I don't fully understand in detail. For example what is `only_full_group_by` and what does it do when turned on/off?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant I had add more explain for that hope that help