# MySQL-Query for getting a report

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I am working on `The mySQL` database. Here is my [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nNFQbRXji1ZEwXoDQbQ1gE/4). Need output like below.

[image]

I have used the below query

```
select 
    a.product_name as 'Product Name', 
    a.product_model 'Product Model', 
    c.batch_id as 'Batch', 
    b.rate as 'Sale Price', 
    c.supplier_rate as 'Purchase Price', 
    sum(b.quantity) as 'IN-QTY', 
    sum(c.quantity) as 'OUT-QTY', 
    (sum(b.quantity)-sum(c.quantity)) as 'Stock', 
    (sum(b.quantity)-sum(c.quantity)*b.rate) as 'Stock Sale Price', 
    (sum(b.quantity)-sum(c.quantity)*c.supplier_rate) as 'Stock Purchase Price'
from 
    product_information a 
    left join product_purchase_details b on a.product_id = b.product_id
    left join invoice_details c on a.product_id = c.product_id
GROUP BY 
    b.batch_id
```

**Output**

[image]

In the above image the `In-QTY`, `Out-Qty`, `Stock`, `Stock Sale Price` and `Stock Purchase Price` is wrong.

**Update 1**

The fiddle has 5 tables and from the below information I have tried to carry out my desired result

1. Product Name and Product Model from **product_infortmation** table
2. Batch from **invoice_details or product_purchase_details**
3. Sale price is the price entered at the time of purchase. So it's the `rate` from **product_purchase_details** table
4. Purchase price is the `supplier_rate` taken from **invoice_details** table
5. In-Qty is the `quantity` at the time of purchase and taken from **product_purchase_details** table
6. Out-Qty is the `quantity` at the time of invoice taken from the **invoice_details** table.
7. Stock is **In-QTY - Out-Qty**
8. Stock Sale Price is **Stock * Sale Price**
9. Stock Purchase Price is **IN-QTY * Purchase Price**

**Update 2**
Updated The [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nNFQbRXji1ZEwXoDQbQ1gE/4)

```
Select   Product_Name,Product_Model,Batch,Sale_Price,Purchase_Price,IN_QTY,OUT_QTY, (IN_QTY-OUT_QTY) as STOCK,((IN_QTY-OUT_QTY)*Sale_Price)as Stock_Sale_Price, IN_QTY*Purchase_Price as Stock_Purchase_Price
from
(SELECT b.product_name as 'Product_Name',b.product_model as 'Product_Model',a.batch_id as 'Batch',sum(a.quantity) as 'IN_QTY',a.rate as 'Purchase_Price',0 as 'Sale_Price',
0 as 'OUT_QTY'
FROM `product_purchase_details` a
inner join product_information b on a.product_id = b.product_id
GROUP by a.batch_id

UNION ALL

SELECT  0 as 'Product_Name',0 as 'Product_Model',0 as 'Batch',0 as 'IN_QTY',0 as 'Purchase_Price',a.supplier_rate as 'Sale_Price',sum(a.quantity) as 'OUT_QTY'
FROM invoice_details a
GROUP by a.batch_id 
)z
group by Batch
```

**Output**

[image]

Again the output is not what I desired.

**Note** There can be no sale of any particular batch.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Becasue older version of mysql sql_mode is not eqaul only_full_group_by as default. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72197717/sql-select-and-count-without-groupby/72197758#72197758

Comment: If you use the version 5.6 that might work with no error(but result might not as you expect) https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nNFQbRXji1ZEwXoDQbQ1gE/2

Comment: @D-Shih i have down-graded the version to 5.6.

Comment: @Moeez You should fix your query and move to the latest version of mysql rather than downgrading . Anyway grouping by batch makes no sense if you want to also show product name product model etc within batch. on the other hand if you just want to summarise by batch drop all the other stuff.

Comment: @P.Salmon I want to get the batch-wise stock details that's why I am doing it

Comment: @P.Salmon I have added some details

Answer (score 0):

The SUMs are too large, correct?

When `JOINing` and doing `SUMs` (or `COUNTs`, etc), please note that the `JOIN` is done *first*.  This generates an intermediate file containing all relevant combinations of all the Joined tables.  *Then* the `SUMs` (etc) are computed.

If a `SUM` should be against less than the Join of all the tables, then it needs to be computed in a subquery.  Depending on the situation, it might be done in either of these ways:

```
SELECT ...,
       ( SELECT SUM(...) FROM ... ) AS total_foo,
       ...
    FROM ...
    JOIN ...
```

Or

```
SELECT ...,
       sums.total_foo,
       ...
    FROM ( SELECT SUM(...) AS total_foo, ... FROM ... ) AS sums
    JOIN ...
```

The first one usually works well if the `SUM` is coming from a single table, independent of the other tables.

The second is often better if you need to compute multiple `SUMs` in one table before combining with the other tables.

In either reformulation, it may be valid to have a `JOIN` in the subquery -- perhaps 2 tables are needed to get the correct tally.

Comment: I have updated the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nNFQbRXji1ZEwXoDQbQ1gE/4) as well you can check

Answer (score 0):

As Rick James noted, it makes sense to aggregate the purchase and invoice information separately first and then join them.  Here's what aggregating on the purchase looks like:

---

**Purchase**

```
SELECT
  a.product_name as 'Product Name',
  a.product_model as 'Product Model',
  b.batch_id as 'Batch ID',
  b.rate as 'Sale Price',
  SUM(b.quantity) as 'IN-QTY'
FROM
  product_information a
  JOIN product_purchase_details b
    ON a.product_id = b.product_id
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4
ORDER BY
  1, 2, 3;
```

| Product Name | Product Model | Batch ID | Sale Price | IN-QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 1 | 400.00 | 3.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 111 | 400.00 | 8.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 112 | 500.00 | 5.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 12345 | 400.00 | 500.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 123456 | 400.00 | 50.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 786 | 400.00 | 500.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 78879 | 500.00 | 200.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 799 | 600.00 | 10.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | cxz | 200.00 | 70.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | fgd | 400.00 | 15.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | KBER | 400.00 | 30.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | poo | 800.00 | 80.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | pop | 400.00 | 20.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | vcx | 400.00 | 40.00 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 12348 | 500.00 | 500.00 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 211 | 500.00 | 500.00 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 212 | 500.00 | 200.00 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 744 | 750.00 | 10.00 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 788 | 500.00 | 500.00 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 799 | 600.00 | 520.00 |
| MD | 1546 | 12345 | 400.00 | 500.00 |
| MD | 1546 | 123489 | 400.00 | 200.00 |
| MD | 1546 | 788788 | 400.00 | 100.00 |
| MD | 1546 | czswe | 1000.00 | 50.00 |
| MD | 1546 | wer | 400.00 | 25.00 |

---

Now, similarly for the invoice:

---

**Invoice**

```
SELECT
  a.product_name as 'Product Name',
  a.product_model as 'Product Model',
  c.batch_id as 'Batch ID',
  c.supplier_rate as 'Purchase Price',
  SUM(c.quantity) as 'OUT-QTY'
FROM
  product_information a
  JOIN invoice_details c
    ON a.product_id = c.product_id
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4
ORDER BY
  1, 2, 3;
```

| Product Name | Product Model | Batch ID | Purchase Price | OUT-QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 12345 | 400 | 80.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 123456 | 400 | 50.00 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 78879 | 437.5 | 10.00 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 211 | 564.286 | 1.00 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 212 | 564.286 | 2.00 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 744 | 564.286 | 6.00 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 788 | 533.333 | 500.00 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 799 | 533.333 | 10.00 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 799 | 590 | 10.00 |
| MD | 1546 | 12345 | 400 | 10.00 |
| MD | 1546 | 123489 | 400 | 20.00 |

---

So you can join these tables by both the product id and the batch id before calculating the rest of the statistics.  In the following example, I'm joining in a way that if the batch doesn't exist in the aggregated invoice, then the `OUT-QTY` and `Purchase Price` are set to 0.

---

**Final**

```
WITH tbl_purchase as (
  SELECT
    product_id,
    batch_id,
    rate,
    SUM(quantity) as quantity
  FROM
    product_purchase_details b
  GROUP BY
    1, 2, 3
),
tbl_invoice as (
  SELECT
    product_id,
    batch_id,
    supplier_rate,
    SUM(quantity) as quantity
  FROM
    invoice_details
  GROUP BY
    1, 2, 3
),
agg as (
SELECT
  b.product_id,
  b.batch_id,
  b.rate,
  CASE
    WHEN c.supplier_rate is NULL THEN 0
    ELSE c.supplier_rate
  END as 'supplier_rate',
  b.quantity as 'in_quantity',
  CASE
    WHEN c.quantity IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE c.quantity
  END as 'out_quantity'
FROM
  tbl_purchase b
  LEFT JOIN tbl_invoice c
    ON b.product_id = c.product_id AND b.batch_id = c.batch_id
)
SELECT
  a.product_name as 'Product Name',
  a.product_model as 'Product Model',
  agg.batch_id as 'Batch',
  agg.rate as 'Sale Rate',
  agg.supplier_rate as 'Purchase Rate',
  agg.in_quantity as 'IN-QTY',
  agg.out_quantity as 'OUT-QTY',
  agg.in_quantity - agg.out_quantity as 'Stock',
  (agg.in_quantity - agg.out_quantity)*agg.rate as 'Stock Sale Price',
  (agg.in_quantity - agg.out_quantity)*agg.supplier_rate as 'Stock Purchase Price'
FROM
  product_information a
  LEFT JOIN agg
    ON a.product_id = agg.product_id
ORDER BY
  1, 2;
```

| Product Name | Product Model | Batch | Sale Rate | Purchase Rate | IN-QTY | OUT-QTY | Stock | Stock Sale Price | Stock Purchase Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 1 | 400.00 | 0 | 3.00 | 0 | 3.00 | 1200.0000 | 0 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 111 | 400.00 | 0 | 8.00 | 0 | 8.00 | 3200.0000 | 0 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 112 | 500.00 | 0 | 5.00 | 0 | 5.00 | 2500.0000 | 0 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 12345 | 400.00 | 400 | 500.00 | 80.00 | 420.00 | 168000.0000 | 168000 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 123456 | 400.00 | 400 | 50.00 | 50.00 | 0.00 | 0.0000 | 0 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 786 | 400.00 | 0 | 500.00 | 0 | 500.00 | 200000.0000 | 0 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 78879 | 500.00 | 437.5 | 200.00 | 10.00 | 190.00 | 95000.0000 | 83125 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | 799 | 600.00 | 0 | 10.00 | 0 | 10.00 | 6000.0000 | 0 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | cxz | 200.00 | 0 | 70.00 | 0 | 70.00 | 14000.0000 | 0 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | fgd | 400.00 | 0 | 15.00 | 0 | 15.00 | 6000.0000 | 0 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | KBER | 400.00 | 0 | 30.00 | 0 | 30.00 | 12000.0000 | 0 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | poo | 800.00 | 0 | 80.00 | 0 | 80.00 | 64000.0000 | 0 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | pop | 400.00 | 0 | 20.00 | 0 | 20.00 | 8000.0000 | 0 |
| Dumbles | 2022 | vcx | 400.00 | 0 | 40.00 | 0 | 40.00 | 16000.0000 | 0 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 12348 | 500.00 | 0 | 500.00 | 0 | 500.00 | 250000.0000 | 0 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 211 | 500.00 | 564.2860107421875 | 500.00 | 1.00 | 499.00 | 249500.0000 | 281578.71936035156 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 212 | 500.00 | 564.2860107421875 | 200.00 | 2.00 | 198.00 | 99000.0000 | 111728.63012695312 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 744 | 750.00 | 564.2860107421875 | 10.00 | 6.00 | 4.00 | 3000.0000 | 2257.14404296875 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 788 | 500.00 | 533.3330078125 | 500.00 | 500.00 | 0.00 | 0.0000 | 0 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 799 | 600.00 | 533.3330078125 | 520.00 | 10.00 | 510.00 | 306000.0000 | 271999.833984375 |
| Hammer Strength | 124578 | 799 | 600.00 | 590 | 520.00 | 10.00 | 510.00 | 306000.0000 | 300900 |
| MD | 1546 | 12345 | 400.00 | 400 | 500.00 | 10.00 | 490.00 | 196000.0000 | 196000 |
| MD | 1546 | 123489 | 400.00 | 400 | 200.00 | 20.00 | 180.00 | 72000.0000 | 72000 |
| MD | 1546 | 788788 | 400.00 | 0 | 100.00 | 0 | 100.00 | 40000.0000 | 0 |
| MD | 1546 | czswe | 1000.00 | 0 | 50.00 | 0 | 50.00 | 50000.0000 | 0 |
| MD | 1546 | wer | 400.00 | 0 | 25.00 | 0 | 25.00 | 10000.0000 | 0 |

---

I think this is what you're looking for - though it doesn't match your first screenshot.